# what is the difference between consistent hashing and sticky sessions?

Tags: performance, load-balancing, distributed-computing, consistent-hashing, sticky-session

My understanding of consistent hashing is that it is used to minimize rehashing overhead and that request is served to the next nearest worker in the ring to the hash value of the request. So this guarantees same requests to hash to the same worker as long as the worker is up and the hash function doesn't change.

Similar sticky sessions may use cookies to add information to route subsequent requests to the same worker.

Does sticky session use consistent hashing internally or does it use some kind of a map/cache to route sessions to the same worker and both are essentially different entities?